# Regresar a la página anterior tras iniciar o cerrar sesión

Tags: php, html

Tengo un botón para logearse/desloguearse en todas mis vistas y la idea es que, independiente de la que se accione, regrese a la misma vista.

**La barra en mi vista:**

[image: Captura de pantalla del aspecto del botón de "Ingresar"]

**HTML del botón:**

```
<li class="nav-item" style=""><a href="Vista/ingreso.php" class="nav-link" style="font-weight: bold; color:#0b4892"><span class="icon-user" style="font-size: 25px; margin-right: 5px;color:#0b4892"></span>Ingresar</a></li>
```

**Ingreso vista:**

[image: Captura de pantalla del aspecto del formulario de inicio de sesión]

**Ingreso HTML:**

```
<form action="../Modelo/validar_usuario.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
            <label><strong>Correo</strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="correo" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label><strong>Password</strong></label>
           <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="btningreso" class="btn btn-flat m-b-30 m-t-30" style="background-color: #1e2947; color: white">
             <strong><font size=3>Ingresar</font></strong>
      </button>
</form>
```

**Validador PHP:**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require_once "conexion.php";
 $conexion=conexion();
 $correo=$_POST['correo'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 $consulta="SELECT * from usuario where correo='$correo' and pass='$password'";
 $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
 $filas=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 
 if ($filas>0)
 {
   header("location:../index.php");
   $_SESSION['correo']=$correo;
 }
 else
 {
   echo '<script>alert("Usuario o Password Incorrecto")</script>';
   echo "<script>location.href='../Vista/Ingreso.php'</script>";
 }
?>
```

La función de desloguearse trabaja de manera similar.

Comment: Luis limpia la sesion del usuario y despues le haces un redirect al login, si el resto de paginas tienes que verificas el usuario lo mandara siempre al login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes solucionar el problema de dos formas:

- Proporcionando la URL de retorno en la URL enlazada.
- Almacenar la cabecera `Referer` enviada por el navegador web.

Cada una tiene sus ventajas e inconvenentes.

---

**Proporcionando la URL**

El HTML del botón deberías cambiarlo por la siguiente URL:

```
Vista/ingreso.php?retorno=<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>
```

El formulario quedaría así:

```
<li class="nav-item" style="">
  <a href="Vista/ingreso.php?retorno=<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" class="nav-link" style="font-weight: bold; color:#0b4892">
    <span class="icon-user" style="font-size: 25px; margin-right: 5px;color:#0b4892"></span>Ingresar
  </a>
</li>
```

Deberías cambiar el formulario PHP para que éste almacene y mande al validador la URL de retorno, que debería ser:

```
$_GET["retorno"] ?? $_POST["retorno"] ?? ""
```

Usará el valor enviado por GET de la vista originaria, o bien el enviado por el formulario (si volvemos a él por credenciales incorrectas, por ejemplo) o bien una cadena vacía.

El formulario quedaría así:

```
<form action="../Modelo/validar_usuario.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="retorno" value="<?= $_GET["retorno"] ?? $_POST["retorno"] ?? "" ?>" />
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Y, por último, quedaría modificar el validador para que te enviara a la URL almacenada:

```
if ($filas > 0) {
    header("Location: ". ($_POST["retorno"] ?? "../index.php"));
    $_SESSION['correo'] = $correo;
    exit(0);
}
```

Por cierto, tu código puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Te recomiendo que uses consultas preparadas o que, al menos, escapes los campos del formulario recibidos antes de agregarlos al código SQL.

---

**Almacenando la cabecera `Referer`**

Este caso es más sencillo ya que solo hay que modificar el formulario de inicio de sesión y el de validación.

El formulario de inicio de sesión debería almacenar la página de referencia:

```
<form action="../Modelo/validar_usuario.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="retorno" value="<?= $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ?? $_POST["retorno"] ?? "" ?>" />
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Y el validador quedaría exactamente igual que antes:

```
if ($filas > 0) {
    header("Location: ". ($_POST["retorno"] ?? "../index.php"));
    $_SESSION['correo'] = $correo;
    exit(0);
}
```

---

**Extra: problemas de inyección SQL**

El validador debería ser el que se muestra a continuación:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "conexion.php";

$conexion = conexion();

/* Escapamos la información que se concatenará al código SQL */
$correo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['correo']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['password']);
$consulta = "
    SELECT *
    FROM usuario
    WHERE
        correo='$correo'
        AND pass='$password'
";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

/* Cuando no hay registros devuelve null */
if (empty($registro) === false) {
    header("Location: ". ($_POST["retorno"] ?? "../index.php"));
    $_SESSION['correo'] = $registro["correo"];
    exit(0);
}
?>
<script>
  alert("Usuario o Password Incorrecto");
  /* Vamos a generar la ruta de vuelta manteniendo el valor de "retorno" */
  destino = new URL("../Vista/Ingreso.php", location);
  destino.searchParams.append(
      "retorno",
      <?= json_encode($_POST["retorno"] ?? "") ?>
  );
  location.href = destino.href;
</script>
```

Comment: No capte bien la parte js, para que es la linea? destino = new URL("../Vista/Ingreso.php", location);  de donde sale la variable location?

Comment: Todas las variables de javascript, por defecto, se crean y acceden como propiedades del objeto global `window`, por lo que se trata de [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/location). Es una de las maneras de resolver una URL relativa.